# shell script: emacs does not align case if pattern involves $

Tags: shell, align

Let us start with an unaligned piece of code

```
case $word in
pattern1)
command1
;;
*)
command_defaultcase
;;
esac
```

I can align this code by selecting the lines and pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>. The result is:

```
case $word in
    pattern1)
        command1
        ;;
    *)
        command_defaultcase
        ;;
esac
```

However, the result is different if the pattern involves `$`:

```
case $word in
    $pattern1)
    command1
    ;;
    *)
        command_defaultcase
        ;;
esac
```

The `emacs` version I use is `GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.23) of 2015-02-20 on lxdist01`.

What is wrong?

Comment: I can't replicate that in Emacs 25.3.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @phils I updated my question.

Comment: Also not reproduceable on emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: @Tobias, I also cannot reproduce the problem in `Emacs 24.5.1`.

Comment: So, why not using emacs 24.5.1?

Comment: @Tobias, for the sake of this question, imagine that switching to `emacs 24.5.1` is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems clear that there was a bug in `sh-mode` in Emacs 23.1 which was fixed in some subsequent version (certainly by 24.5). So that explains "what is wrong".

If you cannot upgrade Emacs, you could try just using the `sh-script.el` from a newer version -- it's possible that it will work.

n.b. Any newer version which *depends* on lexical binding will not work correctly in Emacs 23 (although the presence of `-*- lexical-binding:t -*-` does not necessarily mean that the library *depends* on it -- it may just mean that it was confirmed to work with it as-is).